# How to forward Facebook Messenger message to SMS

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to forward your Facebook messages to your phone via SMS? Maybe using like Twilio?

Comment: This question doesn't meet the [current quality standards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Answer (score 1):

Easier is having Messenger App managing the SMSs too on your phone (if you send sms from your messenger is already enabled to that), and after just simply forwarding some message to the contact having that phone number. The contact with telephone number will appear with magenta color instead with a photo or something on his icon.

Or, if you don't have enabled managing both (Facebook contacts and SMSs) you cant just forwarding. But you can simply copy/paste from Messenger to the Messages app (app intended for SMS).

Comment: are you talking about SMS messages in Messenger. I believe that features is only available for Android? I have an iPhone/iOS device.